# Mongodb embed structure updating and searching?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Playing with MongoDB to store results from a nmap network scan, and trying to figure out the best way to structure the data.

At the moment I have the following :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("525f94097025166583e18eba"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "services" : [ 
        {
            "port" : "22",
            "port_info" : [ 
                {
                    "product" : "ssh",
                    "version" : "1.0"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "port" : "80",
            "port_info" : [ 
                {
                    "product" : "apache",
                    "version" : "2.0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can find for example hosts with port 22 open, example against just 127.0.0.1 with this

```
db.hosts.find({ ip : "127.0.0.1"}, {"services" : { $elemMatch : { port : "22" }}})
```

But I am not sure, how to find for example all hosts, which has "product" : "ssh"
try does, but I get a syntax error

```
db.hosts.find({ ip : "127.0.0.1"}, { services.port_info : { $elemMatch : { product : "ssh"    }}})
```

Then let's say I want to add another element to "port_info" maybe something like
    protocol : tcp

how would I do a update, where I say something like update where ip : 127.0.0.1 and product is ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The syntax error is because you have to use quotes around `services.port_info`
2. However, `$elemMatch` [in nested fields is currently unsupported](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7625) anyway
3. Fortunately, you don't need `$elemMatch` for this kind of query

This should do:

```
db.hosts.find({ ip : "127.0.0.1"}, { "services.port_info.product" : "ssh" });
```

`$elemMatch` is required if you want to match multiple criteria inside the array object, for instance "find all where port is 9000 and protocol is UDP". That would be unsupported with your data structure. I'm not sure why `port_info` is an array of objects (maybe for uncertain situtations where a port could belong to two different services?) - if it were a single object, even the `$elemMatch` would be supported.

Also, keep in mind that such a query will always return the entire object.