# Updating a embedded array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I asked on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432909/mongodb-embed-structure-updating-and-searching) on how to find entries in a embedded MongoDB document.
Sitting with a new issue now. My structure looks like :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5260c4bd95f8e3ad08000000"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "services" : [ 
        {
            "port" : "22"
        }
    ]}
```

I want to add a new key/value pair to services.port where the port is 22, so that it looks like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5260c4bd95f8e3ad08000000"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "services" : [ 
        {
            "port" : "22",
            "product" : "ssh"
        }
    ]}
```

This is the update I run :

```
db.hosts.update({ "ip" : "127.0.0.1" }, { $addToSet : { services : { "port" : "22", "product" : "ssh" }}});
```

And this is what I am getting

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5260c4bd95f8e3ad08000000"),
    "ip" : "127.0.0.1",
    "services" : [ 
        {
            "port" : "22"
        }, 
        {
            "port" : "22",
            "product" : "ssh"
        }
    ]}
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? Should I delete the entry and recreate it?

Answer (score 2):

`$addToSet` performs a `$push` operation if the element doesn't exist. Since `{ "port" : "22", "product" : "ssh" }` doesn't already exist in the `services` array, a new document is `push`ed to `services`.

```
db.hosts.update({ "ip" : "127.0.0.1" }, { $set: { "services.0.product": "ssh" }});
```

This uses `'0'` to reference the first element of the `services` array and set its `product` property to `"ssh"`. It works because arrays are also objects with each index position being a property/key.